# Do you still have to report to the IRS if you sold no stock, and your total dividends for the year were less than $0.05?

Tags: taxes, stocks, irs, dividends, form-1099

If you own stock, but did not sell any in the previous year, and your dividends for the year totaled less than $0.05, do you still have to report any of it to the IRS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The minimum for the company or brokerage to issue you a 1099-DIV is $10. Technically, you still ought to report the income, even if less than $10, however, the rounding down of $0.05 to $0 will also make the issue moot. You can probably safely ignore it.